# How to check if Graph is connected

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I have a un-directed graph, and wanted to know a node is connected to another node or not?

for example

```
0 1 0
1 0 1 
0 1 0
```

In this node 1 is connected to node 3 ( because there is a path from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 hence 1-3 is connected )

I have written programs which is using DFS, but i am unable to figure out why is is giving wrong result.

*I don't want to keep any global variable*   and want my method to return true id node are connected using *recursive* program

```
public static boolean isConnectedGraph(int[][] graph, int start, int end,
        int visited[]) {
    visited[start] = 1;
    if (graph[start][end] == 1) {
        System.out.println("Yes connected....");
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < graph[0].length; i++) {
        if (graph[start][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0) {
            visited[i] =1;
            isConnectedGraph(graph, i, end, visited);

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you recursively calling `isConnectedGraph`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't do anything with the result of the recursive call `isConnectedGraph(graph, i, end, visited);`. You should assign it to a variable, and if it is `true` - return `true`.

Change the main loop to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph[0].length; i++) {
    if (graph[start][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0) {
        visited[i] =1;
        if (isConnectedGraph(graph, i, end, visited)) return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I mistakenly gave wrong code, now edited please check, but still I am u mean, can u please write improved code

Comment: @Arvind Editted, the issue was mentioned in old answer as well, but I now focused on it.

Comment: @Arvind Yes, look at the recursive call, it's in an if condition now